# Can we create start date and end date using react date picker?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to the reactjs and I wanted to create start date and end date using react-date-picer.
Can anyone suggest ne how can I do this, by using react date picker

Answer (score 0):

```
<strike>
you can use react date picker by using two field date picker,

() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date("2014/02/08"));
  const [endDate, setEndDate] = useState(new Date("2014/02/10"));
  return (
    <>
      <DatePicker
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
        selectsStart
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
      />
      <DatePicker
        selected={endDate}
        onChange={(date) => setEndDate(date)}
        selectsEnd
        startDate={startDate}
        endDate={endDate}
        minDate={startDate}
      />
    </>
  );
};
</strike>
```

Comment: Appreciate Your help